# Обновление кадра, скорость и время (Vulkan + WinApi)

Tags: c++, winapi, разработка-игр, vulkan

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь разобраться в Vulkan, но вопрос скорее даже не по нему. В общем дошел до стадии описания перемещений камеры в пространстве когда зажаты какие-либо кнопки на клавиатуре (по задумке WASD). Набросал небольшую структуру описывающую положение камеры, вот она:

```
struct{
    struct { float x = 0.0f; float y = 0.0f; float z = 0.0f; } position;
    struct { float x = 0.0f; float y = 0.0f; float z = 0.0f; } rotation;
    struct { int x = 0; int y = 0; int z = 0; } movement;
    float movementSpeed = 0.1f;

    bool IsMoving() const {
        return this->movement.x != 0 || this->movement.y != 0 || this->movement.z != 0;
    };
} camera;
```

Переменная movement, в этой структуре, по сути отвечает за направление (1 - положительное, -1 - отрицательное, 0 - не двигается по данной оси). Эта переменная меняется при нажатии и отпускании клавиш (в оконной процедуре).

Затем я подумал, что если в цикле просто увеличивать значения позиций по разным осям на определенную величину, то в итоге движение будет происходить быстрее на более быстрых компьютерах (где цикл работает быстрее), и медленнее на слабых. Поэтому я решил что нужно привязаться ко времени. Создал в начале программы переменную содержащую время последнего кадра

```
// Время последнего кадра (точнее последней итерации цикла)
time_point<high_resolution_clock> lastFrameTime;
```

А затем в самом цикле я делаю примерно следующее

```
    // Сколько наносекунд прошло с последней итерации
    int64_t delta = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now() - lastFrameTime).count();

    // Сколько прошло миллисекунд
    float deltaMs = (float)delta / 1000000;

    // Если камера движется (какая-то из кнопок зажата)
    // следует обновить ее положение
    if (camera.IsMoving()) {
        camera.position.x += ((float)camera.movement.x * (camera.movementSpeed * deltaMs));
        camera.position.y += ((float)camera.movement.y * (camera.movementSpeed * deltaMs));
        camera.position.z += ((float)camera.movement.z * (camera.movementSpeed * deltaMs));
    }

    // Обновить рендерер и отрисовать кадр
    vkRenderer->SetCameraPosition(camera.position.x, camera.position.y, camera.position.z);
    vkRenderer->Update();
    vkRenderer->Draw();

    // Обновить время последнего кадра
    lastFrameTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
```

То есть я получаю время, которое прошло с последнего кадра, и умножаю на него скорость, чтобы получить необходимый путь, который нужно прирастить к положению за кадр (банальное s=vt).

**Казалось бы все должно быть хорошо, но нет!**

Когда я делаю так, как описал выше, камера двигается резкими рывками. То есть не плавно, будто время итерации всякий раз сильно варьируется (кстати это правда так! Я выводил это время в консоль, и оно правда иногда по каким-то причинам слишком велико. В основном это 250-300 наносекунд, но иногда доходит до нескольких тысяч). Но когда я вместо deltaMs, при вычислении позиции, использую какую-то константную величину - все начинает двигаться плавно, что вообще странно (ведь если время цикла такое переменчивое, то в тот момент когда он подтормаживает, камера должна двигаться вроде как медленнее)

И собственно вопрос - где и что я не так делаю? Почему программа ведет себя так странно? Может я не учитываю каких-то мелочей, которые происходят неявно при работе с этими таймерами? Или может быть я в корне не верно рассуждаю? За ранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: Вы явно делаете в цикле что-то еще. Приведите настоящий код. Иначе дельта между циклами всегда была бы почти 0. Кроме того, время, затраченное на рендер не учитывается. И да, тут есть принципиальная проблема - гранулированность движения камеры зависит от частоты кадров.

Comment: Для подобной задачи вряд ли нужна высокая точность, реально камеру нужно двигать раз в тик (например, 60 раз в секунду). И я бы лучше использовал `std::steady_clock` во избежание проблем при засыпании системы и подобных. Кроме того, вычислять `lastFrameTime` нужно в то же время, что и `delta`, то есть сначала нужно записать текущее время в переменную и не вызывать `...clock::now()` несколько раз (иначе время, затраченное на вычисления, создаёт случайное отклонение).

Comment: Огромное спасибо, Ariox. Когда перестал запрашивать clock::now() несколько раз за итерацию, действительно все стало работать корректно. А что имелось в виду под проблемами засыпания системы? Ну а насчет того, что не учитывается время рендеринга - если не ошибаюсь, рендеринг протекает ассинхронно (то есть внутри самого рендерера производится синхронизация для показа именно готового изображения, но сама работа происходит на устройстве и вроде как ее выполнение не блокирует.. основной поток. Так что его особо можно и не учитывать, но не знаю насколько это правильно и могу ошибаться конечно).